# How do I configure a scheme to get the least privileges for e specific user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently trying to secure my database.

For this purpose the user *webread* should only be able to access objects from the schema *web*. The underlying tables/views should not be available to the user in anyway other way.

I have read this super [article](https://www.insidesql.org/blogs/andreaswolter/2016/02/schema-design-for-sql-server-recommendations-for-schema-design-with-security-in-mind) to understand the concept of least privilege and how I can set it up in safe way.

Unfortunately I don't understand exactly how I have to do that. The setup of the tables is shown in the following script. The testscript is wrote is below.

```
-- Objects
CREATE TABLE Tabelle (daten nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO dbo.Tabelle(daten)VALUES(N'foo')
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.Sicht AS SELECT * FROM Tabelle
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.lesen AS
begin
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tabelle
end
GO
-- objects to secure
CREATE SCHEMA web;
GO
CREATE view web.Sicht AS SELECT * FROM dbo.Tabelle;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE web.lesen AS
begin
    SELECT * FROM dbo.tabelle
end
GO
```

I started with that.....

```
CREATE USER webread WITHOUT LOGIN

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::web TO webread; 
GRANT execute,SELECT ON SCHEMA ::web TO webread;

-- select as dbo
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Tabelle
SELECT * FROM  web.Tabelle

-- select as webread
EXEC AS USER = 'webread'
GO
SELECT current_user
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Tabelle
SELECT * FROM  web.Sicht
REVERT
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Please explain what your end goal is.

Comment: I have specified the requirements in the second paragraph and as well the title (was missleading)

Comment: You keep talking about schemas in your question. That is why I have asked. Restricting access to tables can be done by simply revoking table permissions for this user.

Comment: i found the solution. Just revoke all rights for user webread on both schema (dbo and web) and grant only execute (for SP)  and select (views) to the web schema for user webread. works only if both schema (web and dbo) owned by the same user/principal.  explanations see the link above

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Simply revoke all rights for the user webread on both schemes (dbo and web) and only grant execute (for SP) and select (views) on the web scheme for the user webread. only works if both schemes (web and dbo) belong to the same user/principal.

```
CREATE USER webread WITHOUT LOGIN

deny DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE,EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO webread
deny DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE,EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::web TO webread
grant EXECUTE, SELECT ON SCHEMA::web TO webread
-- execute für SP, select für Views

-- select as dbo
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Tabelle
SELECT * FROM  web.Sicht

-- select as webread
EXEC AS USER = 'webread'
GO
SELECT current_user
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Tabelle
SELECT * FROM  web.Sicht
EXEC  web.lesen
REVERT
```